# How to display terms and conditions in post area?

Tags: plugins, multisite, wp-admin, terms

I'm running a multisite.

I would like to display "Terms and conditions" when user trying to create a new post. 
Users should Click "I agree" link and then proceed to create a new post(wp-admin/post-new.php).

Is there any good plugin available for this? Or can anyone give me some snippets? Looking forward to it. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes there is: [Terms Of Use plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/terms-of-use-2/).

Also able to add the checkbox to signup pages, works with [Formidable forms plugin](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/formidable/) and enables you to add the checkbox before viewing a (front- or backend) page.

Comment: +1 Excellent answer :) oops i already reached my daily vote limit :( . I'll give upvote tomorrow.

Comment: Vote Added.. :)